# Directive got called multiple times when executing unit tests

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

### What I have:

- a 3rd party directive
- my custom directive (view uses the 3rd party directive)
- unit tests (for other components as well, around 300 unit tests)

My directive uses the 3rd party directive within the template like this way:

```
<3rd-party-directive value="bindedValue" style="display:none;"></3rd-party-directive>

<div>{{producedValue}}</div>
```

So nothing magic going there.
I have also unit tests for my custom directive (6 test case).

### The problem:

- 1. If I run unit tests ONLY for my custom directives (6 unit test), it costs:

     - **0.007 sec**
- 2. If I run unit tests WITHOUT my custom directives unit tests (300 unit test), it costs:

     - **2.3 sec**
- 3. If I run unit tests WITH my custom directives as well (306 unit test), it costs:

     - **240 sec.**

Does anybody meet this problem before? I dont want to show my code because it's not about how I implemented my code. Something different going on here...

### Notes:

I run my tests with Karma + Jasmine. Karma uses 100% CPU when 2nd case. When its in the begining of executecution its really fast but later on it's increasingly slowing down.
Like:

1  - 80  unit tests --> 2  sec

81 - 120 unit tests --> 30  sec

121- 180 unit tests --> 90 sec

181- 300 unit tests --> 240 sec (here every unit test costs ~1 second...)

### UPDATE

I made a console.log inside my custom directive and it seems it got called ~600 times!!! But WHY and HOW? I thought unit tests are sandboxed-like, so each 'describe' block has his own sandbox.

Comment: Any luck solving this one?  We're seeing the exact same thing.

Comment: as far as I can recall, the issue was that I had an `describe` block which had a `beforeEach` and more `it` blocks inside.
The problem was that somehow I renamed that block to `it`, so describe became an it block and things went crazy.